# how do I stretch an image to full page height without creating a slider and continuing this page?

Tags: html, css

image-back2!

it is necessary that the white color was the height of the page(ie, did not create a continuation of the page)

there is an image that you want to stretch across the height of the page without creating a scroll below on this page

**code:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>text</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <style>
        body{
              background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat;
              -moz-background-size: cover;
              -webkit-background-size: cover;
              -o-background-size: cover;
              background-size: cover;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-attachment:fixed" topmargin="0">
  <p align="center"><img src="back2.jpg" height="730" width="1300" > </p>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: You are using an image with fixed witdth and height. How do you expect that it should fit the page? Use percentage instead and also set style `margin:0` for `body`.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour it doesn't work)

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I've changed 100 percent and the same garbage)in the end of the page remains

Comment: Aslo remove`<P>` from your codes because paragraph has initial padding and margin

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Yes it helped but how then to put it in the center?

Comment: Use `<div style="text-align:center">` as holder instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ответы на ОГЭ,ЕГЭ,ВПР,ОЛИМПИАДЫ</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <style>
        body{
              background: url(back.jpeg) no-repeat;
              -moz-background-size: cover;
              -webkit-background-size: cover;
              -o-background-size: cover;
              background-size: cover;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-attachment:fixed" topmargin="0">


  <div style="text-align:center"><img src="back2.jpg" height=100% width="1300" > 

</body>
</html>
```